# Implementing .each in Wicegrid (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wice-grid

I have the following column in my Wicegrid table, which iterates through the advisors of a student and lists them in the Wicegrid:

```
g.column name: 'Student Advisor' do |user|
  res=''
  if user.advisors
    user.advisors.each do |advisor|
      advisor.username
    end
  end 
end
```

Wicegrid doesn't allow arrays to be returned inside their columns or at least that is what I understood from the error below:

"**When WiceGrid column block returns an array its second element is expected to be a hash containing HTML attributes for the  tag.**"

Is there another way to have the list of advisors in the table?

Comment: You don't have to use Stack Snippet for your code. Stack Snippet is suppose to be used for code that can be executed (like a small JavaScript and html code). Please use the normal code formatting option (Ctrl-K on windows or the `{ }` button). mudasobwa correctly re-formated your code block, I suggest you look at his edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the requirements properly, the following will return a list of advisors, if exists, concatenated with commas:

```
g.column name: 'Student Advisor' do |user|
  user.advisors.map(&:username).join(', ') if user.advisors
end
```